# Failure to create reproducible example by means of replicate/dput function

Tags: r, import, reproducible-research

Im trying to use `dput()` to create a reproducible example with a large database. The database needs to be large as the reproducible example involves moving averages. The way I've found to do this involves the function `reproduce`, shared here [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by @Ricardo Saporta. `reproduce` is based on `dput()` (code here https://github.com/rsaporta/pubR/blob/gitbranch/reproduce.R).

```
library(data.table) 
library(devtools)
source_url("https://raw.github.com/rsaporta/pubR/gitbranch/reproduce.R")

data <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw/xP1Zd0sC")
setDF(data)
reproduce(data, rows = c(1:100))
```

That code creates `data` dataframe, and then provides a `dput()` output for it. It uses the `rows` argument to output the full dataframe. Yet if I use such output to recreate the dataframe, it fails.

Trying to allocate the `dput()` output to a new dataframe results in incomplete code, requiring me to add three parentheses manually at the end. And after doing so, I get the following error message: "Error in View : arguments imply differing number of rows: 100, 61".

Please not that the `dput()` output from `reproduce` without the `rows = c(1:100)` argument works fine. It just does not output the full dataframe, but rather a sample of it.

```
#This works fine
reproduce(data)
```

Please also note that I used the pastebin method to create this reproducible example. That method does not replace the `dput()` method for my purposes because it fails whenever trying to import data where some columns have spaces between the words (e.g. dataframes with datetime stamps).

**EDIT:** after some further troubleshooting discovered that `reproduce` fails as described above when the `rows` argument is used together with a dataframe containing **4 or more columns**. Will have to find an alternative.

If anyone is interested in testing this, run the code above with the following links, all containing different number of columns:

1) 100x5: http://pastebin.com/raw/xP1Zd0sC

2) 100x4: http://pastebin.com/raw/YZtetfne

3) 100x4: http://pastebin.com/raw/63Ap2bh5

4) 100x3: http://pastebin.com/raw/1vMMcMtx

5) 100x3: http://pastebin.com/raw/ziM1bYQt

6) 100x1: http://pastebin.com/raw/qxtQs5u4

Comment: Trying to produce a reproducible example for an SO question.

Comment: Same problem using `rows=100`.

Comment: Thanks Richard. `dput()` doesn't allow to specify the number of rows. At least no mention of it on its documentation. Its output is a few rows at the beginning and a few at the end. I need to output the whole database, rather than a sample.

Comment: Awesome! Want to put that as answer? I would have saved a lot of time by directly asking how to get `dput()` to output a full database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to `dput()` the first 100 rows of a data set, then you can simply subset the data just prior to running `dput()`.  There doesn't seem to be a need to use the linked function.

```
dput(droplevels(head(data, 100)))  ## or dput(droplevels(data[1:100,]))
```

should do it.

It is, however, peculiar that your try on `reproduce()` did not work.  I would file an issue on the github page for that.  You will likely get a more constructive answer there.

Thanks to @David Arenburg for reminding me about `droplevels()`.  It is useful on this operation if we have factor columns.  "Leftover" levels will be dropped.

Comment: I now realize a benefit of `replicate` vs `dput()` is that the first outputs everything on one row, while `dput()` requires lots of editing before sharing on SO. Its a pitty `replicate` has that little bug.